# Regex error with Jenkins Pipeline emailext

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

I am building Jenkins pipeline scripts and sending email on build status.

```
stage('Sending email') {
        echo "${FINAL_EAR}"
        emailext body: '''$DEFAULT_CONTENT

        The cause of the build:
        ${BUILD_CAUSE}

        current build changes:
        ${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="%a: %r %p \\n--\\"%m\\"", pathFormat="\\n\\t- %p"}

        Changes since the last build:
        ${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_UNSTABLE}

        Artifact location:
        ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^`\\\\$\\\\{FINAL_EAR\\\\}' ->", showTruncatedLines=false}''', replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO', subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT', to: 'blah@blah.com'
    }
```

In above snippet I am facing issue with **regex="^`\\$\\{FINAL_EAR\\}' ->"**. Regex is unable to match the correct value, echo prints value correct. I tried escaping (with or without) $, { and } which has special meaning in regex, still it won't work.

This is the error I see once I receive email "**java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1 ^${FINAL_EAR}' ->  ^**"

*Note:* The actual log contains with `, ' and -> so I need those characters in regex. Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't say I got the answer but rather looking for exact "${FINAL_EAR} ->" I used regex as below

```
${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^`[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*' ->", showTruncatedLines=false}''', replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO', subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT', to: 'blah@blah.com'
```

I don't want to leave this unanswered so wanted to provide the way I implemented.